# screen mirroring in android

Tags: java, android, sockets, mirroring

I want to implement screen mirroring in Android platform.

I am thinking to follow this approach, is there any better way for the same:

1. Open socket connection Android and PC.
2. Capture screen or take screenshot at regular intervals and send it through socket.
3. Display the received image in Canvas

Language: Java, Socket programming

**My questions**

1. Is there any other better way to implement the above feature?
2. How do I capture screen in Android Platform?

Answer (score 0):

it possible but difficult to implement, instead you can use VNC implemention on android .

1) https://code.google.com/p/fastdroid-vnc/

or

2) http://code.google.com/p/android-vnc-server/

or

search android VNC server porting.

Answer (score 0):

The same way I implemented Android screen mirroring which are connected in same network. Code is available @ https://github.com/phaneendrak5757/ScreenMirroring

Comment: I have downloaded it. But it is not working. Plz check.

Comment: @Phaneendra Kasalanati, thanks for sample.its working fine for me.is it possible to perform actions on the mirrored screen?

Comment: does this support control of one screen to another?